# Dynamically using v-model to display results of a property inside a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a an array that I'm looping over with v-for, I don't know the number of items in this array, it's gonna be different every time, so I managed to reach a point where I can enter the values into the input and have them reflected correctly in the data property I set for them,

Now I need to resolve *two* things:

-**First**, after I click edit as you'll see in the code, the current value of the property doesn't appear in the input that has a v-model (I get an empty input box), it's working one-way only.(I can input the data in the empty box and it'll be reflected in the data property as I mentioned above)

-**Secondly**, I need to be able to submit the new data to the server through something like axios, what I don't know is how to assign these new values to variables that I can submit, since I have no idea how many values I'm gonna have each time.

Here's the code for the component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Options</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Student Id</th>
                    <th v-for="quiz in quizzes">
                        {{ quiz.quiz_name }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(student, index) in students">
                    <td v-if="!editing || !currentStudent(student)">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="edit(student, index)" :disabled="editing == true">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td v-if="editing && currentStudent(student)">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Update</button>
                        <a @click="cancelEdit">
                            Cancel
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ index }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ student.full_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ student.email }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ student.secret_id.secret_id }}
                    </td>
                    <td v-for="quiz in student.quizzes" v-if="!editing || !currentStudent(student)">
                        {{ quiz.pivot.score }}
                    </td>
                    <td v-for="(quiz, index) in student.quizzes" v-if="editing && currentStudent(student)">
                        <input v-model="quiz_scores[index]">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['students', 'quizzes'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                editing: false,
                editing_user: '',
                index: '',
                quiz_scores: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            //
        },
        methods: {
            edit(student, index) {
                this.editing_user = student,
                this.index = index,
                this.editing = true
            },
            cancelEdit() {
                this.editing_user = '',
                this.index = '',
                this.quiz_scores = [],
                this.editing = false
            },
            currentStudent(student) {
                return this.editing_user == student
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Of course this is incomplete code, if you have any hints or tips on what I should do, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle to better understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the edit action, your inputs are empty because your v-model `quiz_scores[index]` is always empty.
You can fill it on "Edit" click like:

```
edit(student, index) {
  this.editing_user = student
  this.index = index
  this.editing = true
  student.quizzes.forEach( q => {
    this.quiz_scores.push(q.pivot.score)
  })
}
```

On the same logic, for your update, your can initialize an empty data `new_scores: {}` for example and fill it on click "Update" with whatever you need (current student object, array of scores etc...). Then use `new_scores` in a request to post the data on your server.

Comment: Thank you, you definitely answered both of my questions and I managed to get everything working as expected.
But I have another question if you may, now that everything is updating normally, if I pressed the edit button, and typed a new value, but then pressed cancelled, the new value is still reflected in the front-end, it doesn't get submitted to the back-end to be saved, but it's in the front-end still, any ideas on how to get back the original value?

Comment: I really don't know why. With the snippet you provided in your question and if you didn't change the cancel and edit actions (except with the fix i gave you), everything should work ([Proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/Sovalina/7ofxco9u/)).  
If you have VueJS devtools on your browser maybe check what the `student` from props really contains and returns for `{{ quiz.pivot.score }}`